# External links in the web application not opening in phone browser

Tags: android, mobile, webview, mobile-browser

First of all I have a web application which I made with Flask.It works only in the local IP.Then i wanted to make a mobile app with webview to access the web app from an android application.I have 2 different activities in my app.The first activity is getting the local IP from the user to access the web application.My MainActivity.java is below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActivity2();
        }
    });
}

public void openActivity2(){
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    String text = editText1.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT,text);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In my activity 2 I used webview to view the web application which works on user IP.My Activity2.java is below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


    myWebView.loadUrl("http://" + text + ":5000");

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
```

There is a button in my web application and it opens the Google Authentication page in a new tab.My question is how do i make it possible on my app to redirect the user to his default browser when clicked to that button.Is there a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To open any URL to mobile browser, you can use default `Intent` with `ACTION_VIEW` as action and specify the web URL in the intent data.

For example :

```
public void openWebPage(String url) {
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

For detailed information you can refer this [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Browser).

Comment: Actually I saw this solution but the problem is the url is in a button in the web application that I embedded to webview and it's opening the url in a new tab in my original web application.I think that's the main problem in my case.

Comment: @erkutr In that case, you can try with any dummy url and check.